# Scope of type hints in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I am seeking information on the scope of type hints in Clojure, for instance, if I write

```
(defn big-add [^BigInteger x y] (.add x y))
```

is that the same as

```
(defn big-add [^BigInteger x ^BigInteger y] (.add x y))
```

? Suppose I write

```
(defn big-sum 
  ([] BigInteger/ZERO)
  ([^BigInteger x] x)
  ([^BigInteger x & more] (.add x (apply big-sum more) )))
```

Does Clojure assume that `more` is full of `BigInteger`? Suppose I want to tell it not? Would I do something like

```
(defn foo [^BigInteger x & ^Long more] ...)
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set *warn-on-reflection* true and test your expressions with a function where the type can't be resolved.

REPL:

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
(defn testo [s]
      (str s))
=> #'user/testo

(defn testo [s]
      (.charAt s 1))
=> Reflection warning, NO_SOURCE_PATH:2:8 - call to charAt can't be resolved.

(defn testo [^java.lang.String s]
      (.charAt s 1))
=> #'user/testo

(defn testo [^java.lang.String s s2]
      (.charAt s2 1))
=> Reflection warning, NO_SOURCE_PATH:2:8 - call to charAt can't be resolved.

(defn testo [^java.lang.String s & more]
      (.charAt (first more) 1))
=> Reflection warning, NO_SOURCE_PATH:2:8 - call to charAt can't be resolved.
```

And finally

```
(defn testo [s & ^java.lang.String more]
      (.charAt (first more) 1))
=> CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: & arg cannot have type hint, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)
```

The short answer to each of your questions is no  :(